# Angular patchValue does not work

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to change an object inside my main form object. I made a simple fieldFormStructure first, just to maintain the bare skeleton.

```
     fieldFormStructure = this.fb.group({
            name: '',
            Properties: this.fb.group(
                {
                    referenceTypeData: this.fb.group(
                        {
                            'SourceId': this.fb.array([]),
                            'SourceIdString': '',
                        }),
                    imageTypeData: this.fb.group({
                        'ItemSelectType': '',
                        'Source': this.fb.group({
                            DAMSource: '',
                            ContentStudioSource: '',
                        })
                    }),
                }
            )
        });
```

And then on ngOnInit I initialize the form.

```
this.fieldForm = this.fieldFormStructure;
```

And this works perfectly fine, unless I try to make some changes in it.

On a function change, I am basically trying to reset fieldForm.

```
this.fieldForm.get('Properties').patchValue(_.cloneDeep(this.fieldFormStructure.get('Properties').value));
```

And nothing changes in fieldForm. What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to set all the fields in the form?

Comment: @Chellappan, no, the form has more values, I just chose one for example. reset() basically makes everything null.

Comment: Yes basically if you want to set patch value you have to  wrap the objects inside {} and define which value to change.

Comment: @Chellappan instead of using lodash, I pasted the whole object in patchValue again. That doesn't work as well..

Answer (score 0):

Example if you have form group like

```
this.sampleForm=new FormGroup(
      {
        email:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
        password:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
        gender:new FormControl('male'),
        education:new FormGroup(
          {
            sslc:new FormControl('Pass'),
            hsc:new FormControl('Pass')
          }
        ),
        input:new FormArray([])
      }
    );
```

This is how you have to set patch value

```
 this.sampleForm.patchValue({
    email:'lachu@gmail.com',
    input:['data',''] //for array index 0 i am setting patch value and second 
    one i am setting null value 
  });
```

Comment: But will the validators go away then?

Comment: That's cool. Thanks. Also, one question, if I reset a form which contains formArray, and if that formArray contains any items like [1,2,3], it becomes [null, null, null]. How can I make it []?